# How to efficiently manage lists of arbitrary length?

Tags: list-manipulation, memory

I am running calculations that will generate a list of lists of integers.  Throughout the calculations, the number of lists will increase, and already-existing lists will be added to.  What is the most efficient way to implement this for lists of arbitrary length without causing a bunch of slow list copies?

The following toy code illustrates the problem with random integers.  Using AppendTo[] causes the lists to be copied over and over again.  I will not know the number of lists or their lengths beforehand.  The variable n will be set as high as I have enough virtual memory for.

EDIT:  Just to be really clear, lists will be added and added-to constantly, after every iteration of my ongoing calculation.

```
n=25;
a = {{}};
Do[
  j = RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}];
  AppendTo[a[[j]], RandomInteger[9]];
  If[OddQ[j], AppendTo[a, {}]], {i, 1, n}];
a
```

Comment: This *could* be a problem for [linked lists](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/29734) or a proper `Reap` and `Sow` algorithm.

Comment: Sow and Reap with tags.  The tag will be the sublist index.

Comment: You can have a look at ``Internal`Bag`` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit goes to the people who suggested using Reap and sow.  I just add the worked out example here for completeness sake.

Compared to

```
n = 100000; SeedRandom[1];
Timing[a = {{}};
 Do[j = RandomInteger[{1, Length[a]}];
  AppendTo[a[[j]], i];
  If[OddQ[j], AppendTo[a, {}]], {i, 1, n}];]
```

> {7.92485, Null}

```
n = 100000; SeedRandom[1];
Timing[ len = 1;
 Flatten /@  Part[Reap[Do[j = RandomInteger[{1, len}];
     Sow[i, j];
     If[OddQ[j], len++; Sow[ {}, len]];
     , {i, 1, n}]], 2]; ]
```

> {0.639604, Null}
>   is about 10 times faster.